# Неинтересно или не интересно?

Tags: частица-не

Как правильно написать: «Мне не_интересно, о чём вы там болтаете»? Раздельно или слитно? Я склоняюсь больше ко второму варианту, но выглядит он странно. Может, есть исключения из правил?

Comment: _Что в лоб, что по лбу..._ Оба варианта правильны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ко второму варианту, но выглядит он странно

К варианту слитного написания? Да нет, не стоит к нему склоняться.
Он возможен (как мне представляется), но действительно странновато смотрится при наличии подчиненного предложения.

> Может, есть исключения из правил?

О каком правиле идет речь? Правила написания НЕ с наречиями в целом не ислючают ни слитного ни раздельного написания, но содержат набор указаний, когда конкретно их нужно или возможно использовать. 
Наш вариант не попадает напрямую под императивные указания, но рекомендательно тут раздельное написание предпочтительно.

Я предложил бы простое эмпирическое "правило" собственного изготовления, пригодное в большинстве случаев. Такое.

*Если при написании наречий с частицей НЕ возникают сомнения в выборе варианта, то надо поискать синоним отрицанию (или антоним самому наречию) без отрицательной частицы.  Если такого антонима нет или он не пригоден для замены в тексте, то раздельное написание предпочтительно.*

В нашем случае у "неинтересно" есть синонимы подобные "скучно", "уныло" и т. п., но они плохо подходят для замены. Поэтому скорее всего в примере имеется в виду именно отрицание "интересности", а не новое понятие.

Answer (score 0):

***Мне неинтересно, о чём вы там болтаете.***

Я бы эту задачу решила так.

Существует два состояния: интересно и неинтересно. Кроме того, их можно усилить наречиями и местоимениями.

Получаем следующие варианты: 1) интересно и очень интересно; 2) неинтересно и  совершенно неинтересно, нисколько не интересно. (В усиленном варианте написание НЕ делается по формальным признакам).

КАк мы видим, варианта ***не интересно*** в этой схеме нет, так как раздельное написание ***не интересно***  по смыслу полностью совпадает со слитным написанием ***неинтересно***.

Так зачем использовать отрицательную конструкцию, если существует утверждение с тем же значением.